# How to create a PersonAccount in salesforce using Apex code

Tags: apex, person-accounts

I am trying to create a person account using the following code. Its throwing the following error: `"Invalid constructor syntax, name=value pairs can only be used for SObjects".` How to fix this.

```
Account Acc = new Account(FirstName='test1',LastName='test2',Email='abc@xyz.com');
insert acc;
```

Comment: you need to create an **User Account** or a standard salesforce **Account**?

Comment: Can i have some code piece please.

Comment: sure, but need some details. you need to create an **User** or an **Account**? if you are talking about salesforce **Person Accounts**, then [this](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_person_behavior.htm&language=en_US) will be helpful

Comment: I need to create an Account of person recordtype.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
 Id personAccountRecordTypeId =  Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('PersonAccount').getRecordTypeId();

Account newPersonAccount = new Account();

// for person accounts we can not update the Name field instead we have to update the    FirstName and LastName individually

 newPersonAccount.FirstName = 'Fred';
 newPersonAccount.LastName = 'Smith';
 newPersonAccount.RecordTypeId = personAccountRecordTypeId;
 insert newPersonAccount;
```

You will need to insert Account of RecordType of Person Account .Use developer name of record type as best practice.

If your code is in a Managed Package then you will get errors when you try to create a managed package because you cannot reference PersonAccount fields in a managed package. You will need to reference the fields dynamically to solve this.

The fields can be set like this:

```
newPersonAccount.put('FirstName', 'Fred');
```

Comment: I tried to create the same and when i save the code i get the error as following "Variable does not exist: FirstName" or "Variable does not exist: LastName"

Comment: Is person account enabled in your org?

Comment: Yes i have enabled and i can see it in record type selection too.

Comment: Monith's code works fine for me (with trailing ' added) in a person account org I have. There is probably some other syntax error in your code because the error message would be "Invalid field FirstName for SObject Account" if the issue was the field name.

Comment: **FYI** If your code is in a [Managed Package](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_apps.htm&language=en_US) then you will get errors when you try to create a managed package because you cannot reference PersonAccount fields in a managed package. You will need to reference the fields dynamically to solve this. The fields can be set like this: `newPersonAccount.put('FirstName', 'Fred'); `

Comment: Thank you @MohithShrivastava !! FirstName, LastName, PersonEmail, and PersonContactId were the fields I was looking for that got rid of the errors I was experiencing. Message " Account Name: Unable to create/update fields: Name. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set. "

Answer (score 13):

Just a small correction, now we have a method to retrieve record types by developer name without performing SOQL queries. So, we could do the next:

```
 Id personAccountRecordTypeId =  Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('PersonAccount').getRecordTypeId();
 Account newPersonAccount = new Account();

 newPersonAccount.FirstName = 'Fred';
 newPersonAccount.LastName = 'Smith';
 newPersonAccount.RecordTypeId = personAccountRecordTypeId;
 insert newPersonAccount;
```

Comment: thanks, this the best answer IMHO

Comment: Make sure you use the name that you, as the developer, gave the record type. For example, I called my record type 'Consumer' thinking I might have different types in the future. Therefore, my call is "....get('ConsumerAccount').getRecordTypeId();"