# Creating a Person Account in Salesforce using the REST API

Tags: rest-api, account, contact, person-accounts

I have 2 questions here.

1. I have `Person Account` in salesforce, so if via API if I create a contact , it just creates a contact and not an account, on the other hand If I create an account in salesforce it creates the contact automatically.. is it possible that if i create contact, it creates account as well (maybe some settings in salesforce for admin)?
2. [This page explains how to create account in salesforce.](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_create.htm), but in the docs it is taking only one argument, where as the contact creates lot of arguments like `email, fname, lname`, how can I find all arguments for the Account creation?

Comment: Can you update the link for #2? That goes to the framed-version of the docs, probably not the individual page you meant to reference.

Comment: @DanWatt sure updated

Comment: @DanWatt here is the link view-source:https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_create.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=create|Create|created|Creating|creating|creates|Creates|Created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that there are possibly two ways to do this:

1. Supply a RecordTypeID for a Person Account. See [this answer on a similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/29833/11009%20%22this%20answer%22%20on%20a%20similar%20question)
2. Supply a LastName field, which is a required field for a Person (Contact) but not an Account. See [Inserting Person Account Records Via API](http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-articles/inserting-person-account-records-via-api.html)

To your second question, using the API you can list all fields a couple different ways:

1. List just the fields and their types: /vXX.X/sobjects/Account/
2. List all fields and a lot of data about them (writeable, length, etc): /vXX.X/sobjects/Account/describe/

You can also see all of the field names by looking at the developer docs. Here is the one for [Account](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm).

Comment: the link doesn't provide any API call http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-articles/inserting-person-account-records-via-api.html

Comment: I will try that quickly

Comment: Correct - it is talking about one of the different APIs, not the REST API, but you may be able to try it on the REST API.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes on creating Person Accounts via the API:

- Note you can NOT specify Name for a Person Account, instead you
  specify FirstName and LastName.
- You MUST specify RecordTypeID for a Person Account, if LastName is blank.